# Magento 1.5. Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Model_Session_Exception'

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I get the occasional error below on Magento 1.5.0.1, when it occurs, customers report that they are unable to add items to cart. On clearing their browser cache and hence a new session, there are no issues.

Any ideas on what is happening and how to fix?

```
[17-Aug-2012 04:37:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Model_Session_Exception' in        /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php:341
Stack trace:
       #0 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php(166): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->validate()
       #1 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien->init('checkout', NULL)
       #2 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php(38): Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract->init('checkout')
       #3 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1254): Mage_Checkout_Model_Session->__construct(Array)
       #4 /home/magento/public_html/app/Mage.php(432): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('checkout/sessio...', Array)
       #5 /home/magento/public_html/app/Mage.php(446): Mage::getModel('checkout/sessio...', Array)
       #6 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(54): Mage::getSingleton(' in /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 341
```

Comment: Where do you save session data?

Comment: in file on a rmdisk in the /var/session directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason. Lucky enough, `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Exception` only appears once in the Magento code which is thrown when the session fails validation, and it all came down to the HTTP user agent validator, so I just turned all validation off. No idea why the user agent would change during a session, since these are not hacking attempts and real customers.

Comment: could a browser update cause the user agent string to change during a session?

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently delete transactions / sessions?
It could be that Magento is trying to read a session / transaction from db that doesn't exist

Comment: What type of transactions? No transactions are deleted. Sessions are stored in file on a rmdisk, and there is a cron script that deletes session files older than 3 days. However, gc_maxlifetime and remember_me_seconds are set to 3 days. Could this be the issue? I can't just remove the session clean up cron, since session files will just build up until memory is filled.